# FileUpload Control and Sharepoint 2013

Tags: development

I have a custom SharePoint 2013 App. It contains visual web part with FileUpload control and submit button. Why `if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)` always returns false? I've used this method with ASP.NET applications many times and it was fine. It does not work with SharePoint?

Example:

```
protected void ProcessingList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        FileUploadControl.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"C:\" + FileUploadControl.FileName);
    }
}
```

It works outside SharePoint but didn't works inside..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **have to** insert `<SharePoint:FormDigest runat="server" />` to your WebPartName.ascx file to resolve problem.

Also, check that your solution is "Farm Solution".